# What does Grit do in Renowned Explorers?

Tags: renowned-explorers

Maybe I'm just missing this somewhere, but I can't figure out what the grit stat does in this game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grit affects the enemy hit chance. When the opponents attack a high-grit adventurer, their attacks will "miss" from time to time and do no damage. This applies to both physical and speech attacks. Unfortunately I was unable to find the exact formula.